# Matching multiple values in the same SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've a table with the following structure.

```
Table Name: CustomerStocks

Structure 
Name                     Varchar(25) 
StockSymbol              Varchar(4)
```

Following is the sample of table contents

**Name   StockSymbol**

```
Sam    AAPL
Sam    AMZN
Sam    GOOG

Judy   AAPL
Judy   AMZN

Jen    AMZN

Brian  GOOG
Brian  MSFT
```

The goal is given a customer name, how do I find out the list of other customers who has similar portfolio.  In other words, all the equities of original customers must be present.

Thus, if I'm looking for customers who has similar portfolio of Jen, then the result will be  Judy and Sam.

If I'm searching for customers who has similar portfolio of Judy, then the result will be Sam.

However, if I'm searching for customers with Brian's portfolio, it can return either no rows or just Brian.

Is this possible? If so ,how do I write a sql query to achieve this?

Any help is truly appreciated on this.

Comment: What version of Sql Server -- 2008 or higher by chance?

Comment: sgeddes - Using Sql Server 2008 R2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*(one minor adjustment later...)*

I've not tested this but something like...

```
DECLARE @name VARCHAR(24) = 'Judy';

WITH cte_stocks AS (
    SELECT StockSymbol
    FROM CustomerStocks
    WHERE Name = @name
)
SELECT Name
FROM CustomerStocks cs
LEFT JOIN cte_stocks a ON cs.StockSymbol = a.StockSymbol
GROUP BY cs.Name
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT a.StockSymbol) = (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM cte_stocks)
```

...might do it

Comment: Author may want to include all those whose set is at least the same as .  if so... having should be >= that way its at least all the same stocks. similar but must contain all doesn't mean the exact same in my mind.. but let the OP decide

Comment: @xQbert - Not sure it makes a difference; I'm trying to think of an example that would demonstrate the difference between = and >= in this case.  In the OP's limited setup, >= and = return the same.  Can you provide an example?

Comment: Customer has Stocks A, B, C  User 2 has Stocks A, B, C, D wouldn't this as written exclude user 2?

Comment: @xQbert - Isn't that the same as (in this case) Sam and Judy?  Judy (Customer / `@name`) has A, B (AAPL, AMZN); Sam (User 2) has A, B, C (AAPL, AMZN, GOOG); Sam and Judy appear in result for both `=` and `>=`

Comment: jimbobmcgee , According to your select statement, HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT a.StockSymbol) = (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM cte_stocks). Can you throw some light on how this query works?

Comment: XQbert, Sam has all the stocks that Judy owns and more than that. Thus, if I'm searching on Judy, I would like to have Sam's name too.

Comment: @user373215 - not really; I wrote it a long time ago and recalled it from a snippets folder I have.  The explanation for it always felt a bit too woolly to be a proof, but it has worked for me every time I've tried.  When you break it down, the trick is in counting the *right-hand* side of the join, which basically gives you a count of all the matching rows for each Name.  The join itself filters out the non-matching StockSymbols, while the count of rows from `cte_stocks` tells us what how many StockSymbols are in a 'complete' match.

Comment: Also, if `Name,StockSymbol` is not unique, you'll need to add `DISTINCT` to the CTE...

Comment: @user373215 I'm sorry but not one;)

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
declare @Name varchar(25) = 'Judy'

select * from CustomerStocks cs
where cs.StockSymbol in 
    (select x.StockSymbol 
     from CustomerStocks x 
     where x.Name = @Name)
```

Or to exclude Judy:

```
declare @Name varchar(25) = 'Judy'

select * from CustomerStocks cs
where cs.StockSymbol in 
    (select x.StockSymbol 
     from CustomerStocks x 
     where x.Name = @Name
     and x.Name <> cs.Name)
```

Comment: The rule is the entire set of stocks held by Judy must be matched by other customers and just not one. Thus, if Judy has AAPL, AMZN and GOOG , then the resultant row should be only the list of customers who has all these three stocks and just not one of them.

Comment: This won't work as the asker wanted. The `IN` clause will match any of the associated values, but not necessarily all of them.

Comment: Thanks Robert for your effort. However, this doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so how about this:

```
declare @Name Varchar(25) = 'Judy'
declare @table (StockSymbol varchar(4))

--Get StockSymbols to search for
insert into @table
select cs.StockSymbol 
from CustomerStocks cs 
where cs.Name = @Name
group by cs.StockSymbol


--Match against the people
select cs.Name from CustomerStocks cs
where (select count(*) 
     from CustomerStocks x 
     inner join @table t on x.StockSymbol = t.StockSymbol
     where x.Name = cs.Name
     group by x.StockSymbol) = (select count(*) from @table t)
group by cs.Name
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might work, engine-independent:

```
SELECT target.Name, 'similar_to', others.Name
FROM (
  SELECT Name, COUNT(*) numStocks
  FROM CustomerStocks
  GROUP BY Name
) target
  INNER JOIN (
    SELECT cs1.Name match, cs2.Name otherName, count(*) commonStocks
    FROM CustomerStocks cs1
      INNER JOIN CustomerStocks cs2
        ON cs1.StockSymbol = cs2.StockSymbol
          AND cs1.Name <> cs2.Name
    GROUP BY cs1.Name, cs2.Name
  ) others ON target.Name = others.match
      AND others.commonStocks >= numStocks.numStocks
```

Answer (score 0):

Option with [NOT EXISTS()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188336.aspx) and [EXCEPT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms188055.aspx) operators

```
DECLARE @Name Varchar(25) = 'Judy'       
SELECT *
FROM dbo.CustomerStocks s
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
                  SELECT s3.StockSymbol
                  FROM dbo.CustomerStocks s3
                  WHERE s3.Name = @Name
                  EXCEPT
                  SELECT s2.StockSymbol
                  FROM dbo.CustomerStocks s2
                  WHERE s2.Name = s.Name                        
                  ) AND s.Name != @Name
```

For improving performance use this index

```
CREATE INDEX ix_StockSymbol_CustomerStocks ON CustomerStocks(StockSymbol) INCLUDE(Name)
```

Demo on [**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/476a0/1)